# filter non English FourSquare API

Tags: api, foursquare

FourSquare API return tips in different languages
I couldn't find a way in the API to filter according to a language which means I have to filter it myself. is that correct?

Comment: Did you specify the locale by setting the Accept-Language HTTP header in your request?  https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning

Comment: Thanks, but according to that page the default is English. I didn't specify the locale and I got tips in different languages.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, there's no way to filter tips to a specific language.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue and after a few hours i found a solution [here][1] thanks to the comment of @Robert Harvey
According to four square documentation

> You can specify the locale by setting the Accept-Language HTTP header
>   in your request. Alternatively, you can add a locale=XXX parameter to
>   your request but HTTP header specification is preferred. We currently
>   support en (default), es, fr, de, it, ja, th, tr, ko, ru, pt, and id.
>
> **If nothing is specified, for geographical entities (e.g., city names),
>   we'll fall back to using the language that's most popular in the
>   country for that venue.**
>
> Foursquare also supports many country-specific subcategories in our
>   venue categories. "Suggested Countries" are listed in our category
>   tree for categories that we think will only apply in certain
>   countries.

I am in Pakistan and the location it was returning was in **URDU** language instead of **ENGLISH**

Then i added `locale=en` into my get request url and it worked. Hope this works for you too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't filter tips directly in the API call to `/places/search`, but it is possible with a bit of script to filter the response to `/place/{id}/tips` - you can request the original language when requesting the tips for a given Place ID by adding the `lang` parameter in the query string.

For example, here is a query for a sushi place in Berlin (I got the ID from a `/places/search/` call):

`https://api.foursquare.com/v3/places/4b55a471f964a5202bea27e3/tips?fields=id,created_at,text,lang&limit=10`

Which returns this:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "6269c4eb8778972b685a4313",
        "created_at": "2022-04-27T22:34:19.000Z",
        "text": "Japanes Fried Chicken with gravy! Friendly Stuff and authentic Imbiss",
        "lang": "en"
    },
    {
        "id": "58079fea38faf99d656b5762",
        "created_at": "2016-10-19T16:31:38.000Z",
        "text": "If you love sauce and gravy then you'll love it! Its like little Japan inside too.",
        "lang": "en"
    },
    {
        "id": "53e3383a498e72d166763018",
        "created_at": "2014-08-07T08:26:34.000Z",
        "text": "One and only dish for decades: tori katsu with rice sauce and salad",
        "lang": "en"
    },
    {
        "id": "54bd00fe498e3ef7e0e21fcb",
        "created_at": "2015-01-19T13:05:02.000Z",
        "text": "Place to be. Interior design 0 but the Tori Katsu a 10. Love it!",
        "lang": "en"
    },
    {
        "id": "4fd6ed0ae4b0884f34952d0e",
        "created_at": "2012-06-12T07:17:30.000Z",
        "text": "Well, prices are fine, you can eat soup of the day for 1.20, but food is just not good.",
        "lang": "en"
    },
    {
        "id": "4b55bb2d70c603bb9f3990b4",
        "created_at": "2010-01-19T14:01:17.000Z",
        "text": "a lot of greasy chicken - don't go there. Pricing different from menu.",
        "lang": "en"
    },
    {
        "id": "5558d006498e869b511c0199",
        "created_at": "2015-05-17T17:29:42.000Z",
        "text": "Puh, spezieller Laden, kulinarisch bedenklich, irgendwas mit Huhn, einer deftigen Sauce und einem Berg Reis, dazu Krautsalat. Miso-Suppe mit Dosenchampignons, unglaublich! Irgendwie skurril.",
        "lang": "de"
    },
    {
        "id": "5c4b8b6046e1b6002c8565e3",
        "created_at": "2019-01-25T22:19:12.000Z",
        "text": "Einer meiner Lieblingsessen  von kind auf... super lecker nette bedienung aber kleiner laden aber trotzdem ",
        "lang": "de"
    },
    {
        "id": "59f4f89f1fa763193170c67d",
        "created_at": "2017-10-28T21:37:35.000Z",
        "text": "Eine abwechslungsreiche Karte und authentische Kulisse findet man so nicht noch einmal wieder",
        "lang": "de"
    },
    {
        "id": "52950abe498ec023a24e2fe2",
        "created_at": "2013-11-26T20:55:26.000Z",
        "text": "Sehr einfach sehr lecker...",
        "lang": "de"
    }
]
```

So if you assigned this response to a variable `tips`, you could just run:

```
const enTips = tips.filter(tip => tip.lang === "en");
```